# Create a generic functor in c++98

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

As a school project I have to create a generic functor in c++98.

It must be usable like this:

```
Function<int (char)> f1 = &functionPointer;
f1(’c’);
Function<int (char)> f2 = std::bind(&object, std::placeholders::_1);
f2(’c’);
Function<int (char)> f3 = &object;
f3(’c’);
```

To do that, I defined a class templated to accept callable objects. In this class I defined an interface to abstract the type of the functor stored. The operator= overload in the `Function` class call the operator= overload of the internal functor stored.

This works for function pointer `f1` but not for callable object `f3` or when passing the result of `std::bind`...

```
int funct1(const std::string &str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Function<int(const std::string &)> b = std::bind(&funct1, std::placeholders::_1);
```

This give me this error (I commented the responsible line on the code):

```
invalid cast from type ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to type ‘int’
```

What am I doing wrong here ? :)

My code :

```
template <typename T>
class Function;

template <typename T, typename P>
class Function<T(P)>
{
  typedef T (*fp)(P);

  // Interface representing the generic callable object
  class IFunctorType
  {
  public:
    virtual T operator()(P const &) = 0;
    virtual ~IFunctorType(){};
  };

  // templated class to represent callable object
  template <typename C>
  class FunctorType : public IFunctorType
  {
  public:
    FunctorType() : ftor_ptr_(0) {}
    FunctorType(C const &p) : ftor_ptr_(new C(p)) {}
    FunctorType(FunctorType<C> const &f) : ftor_ptr_(f.ftor_ptr_) {}
    FunctorType(FunctorType<T(P)> const &f) : ftor_ptr_(f.ftor_ptr_) {}
    ~FunctorType() { delete ftor_ptr_; }

    T operator()(P const &p)
    {
      if (ftor_ptr_)
        return ftor_ptr_->operator()(p);
      return T(p); //this line trigger the error
    }

    C *ftor_ptr_;
  };

  // specialised class templated for fonction pointer
  template <typename TT, typename PP>
  class FunctorType<TT(PP)> : public IFunctorType
  {
  public:
    FunctorType() : fptr_(0) {}
    FunctorType(fp p) : fptr_(p) {}
    FunctorType(FunctorType<T(P)> const &f) : fptr_(f.fptr_) {}

    T operator()(P const &p)
    {
      return fptr_(p);
    }

    fp fptr_;
  };

public:
  Function() : ftor_ptr_(0) {}
  Function(Function<T(P)> const &f) : ftor_ptr_(f.ftor_ptr_) {}

  //Contruct from callable object
  template <typename K>
  Function(K const &p) : ftor_ptr_(new FunctorType<K>(p)) {}
  template <typename K>
  Function<T(P)> &operator=(K const &b)
  {
    if (ftor_ptr_)
      delete ftor_ptr_;
    ftor_ptr_ = new FunctorType<K>(b);
    return *this;
  }

  //Contruct from function pointer
  Function(fp p) : ftor_ptr_(new FunctorType<T(P)>(p)) {}
  Function<T(P)> &operator=(fp p)
  {
    if (ftor_ptr_)
      delete ftor_ptr_;
    ftor_ptr_ = new FunctorType<T(P)>(p);
    return *this;
  }

  //Invoke internal functor pointer
  T operator()(P const &p)
  {
    if (ftor_ptr_)
      return ftor_ptr_->operator()(p);
    return T();
  }

  // Actual pointer to functor
  IFunctorType *ftor_ptr_;
};
```

Comment: I'm really confused. `std::bind` was introduced in C++11, so you aren't actually using C++98?

Comment: std::bind is used as a test, only the implementation of the generic functor must be c++98 ;)

Comment: `&object` is not callable.

Comment: Do you *really* need different specializations for taking a copy of a function pointer and taking a copy of an object? (Hint: no). Also, lookup the Rule of Three. This implementation has some memory management issues.

Comment: @Barry So that mean the interface is no longer needed too ?

Comment: Add if wanted to pass function signature with variable number of parameter to my generic functor, what would be the strategy for doing so ? Would I need to copy and paste all my node for many template specialization ?

Answer (score 2):

What is that line supposed to do? It makes not much sense, it tries to convert the parameter to the return type, which is bound to fail, as it does. This is not a problem specific to `std::bind`, but with your handling of function objects:

```
struct Foo {
  int operator()(const std::string&) { return 0; }
};
Function<int(const std::string &)> b = Foo{}; // oh no!
```

You should do the same as you did for function pointers, call the pointer and return the result directly:

```
T FunctorType<C>::operator()(P const &p)
{
    return ftor_ptr_->operator()(p);
}
```

But wait! You might be asking yourself: What if `ftor_ptr_` is null? Well, it is never null! You never use it in a context requiring it to be null. Your default constructor is never used! As well as the other constructors.

Without going into further details, you should be able to hugely simplify your code by removing stuff that you don't need, because you seem to have considered a lot of cases which can never happen.

Comment: What constructor apart from the default constructor is unused in this case ?

Comment: @ThéoChampion The two above the destructor for the primary template and the last one for the specialization.